# Why do mypy and pylint complain about an import which works when I run the code?

Tags: python, import

I have a very very simply python project structured like this:

```
|--daily_checks
     |
     |-daily_checks.py
        |-class DailyCheck
     |-main.py
```

in **main.py** I have an import:

```py
from daily_checks import DailyCheck
```

and that imported class then gets used in **main.py**. When I run my program it succeeds and does what it needs to do. I am running this code in both Visual Studio Code and PyCharm, it runs successfully in both.

However, I'm also running a CI pipeline for this project and in this CI pipeline I'm running pylint and mypy linters.

pylint raises error:

> daily_checks/main.py:1:0: E0611: No name 'DailyCheck' in module 'daily_checks' (no-name-in-module)

mypy raises error:

> daily_checks/main.py:1: error: Module "daily_checks" has no attribute "DailyCheck"

I do not understand why these linters are raising these errors given the code runs successfully.

I've made the project available at https://github.com/jamiet-msm/vscode-dir-demo. The linter errors can be seen in a CI job at: https://github.com/jamiet-msm/vscode-dir-demo/runs/7808692906?check_suite_focus=true. There is a script in README.md that will create a virtualenv to run this in.

Please could someone take a look and explain to me why these linters are failing for code that is, as far as I can tell, valid.

Comment: Because you ran your tools from the wrong folder, get a level deeper.

Comment: I don't have that option unfortunately because I'm using https://github.com/github/super-linter which runs everything from the root

Comment: Then put your starter module in the root and use the folder as a module.